# Why is DDR3 1.5V RAM not working with 1.35V motherboard?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, ddr3

I have a Toshiba C55-A-1M7 laptop with 4GB DDR3L RAM(1600MHz) on a 1.35V motherboard.  I purchased 4GB DDR3 RAM(1600MHz) but the new RAM is not working.  I've tried the new RAM on a 1.5V motherboard and it works properly.

Is there any way to use both of the RAM with my laptop?

Would I need to change BIOS settings?

Can anyone explain the issue and how to fix this?

Comment: The memory you purchased isn’t compared with your hardware

Answer (score 3):

You bought the wrong type of RAM.  DDR3L RAM is low voltage RAM, which runs at 1.35V.  The new RAM you bought is standard DDR3 (no L) and runs at 1.5V.  It cannot function at 1.35V.