# Will 1.5v ram work on 1.35v ram laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, ramdisk

I have a laptop which has a ram of 1.35v. The other slot of ram is empty. I have a ram which working voltage is 1.5v. If I add it on my laptop will it work?

Comment: No;  1.35v modules are not compatible with your machine

Comment: Yeah, sorry mate - see https://superuser.com/questions/1300279/why-is-ddr3-1-5v-ram-not-working-with-1-35v-motherboard